# Rotating png images using javascript css transformations in IE

Tags: javascript, css, html, png

I need to rotate png images (some circle disks). It is done with some help of jQuery:

```
$.fn.rleft = function() {
    return this.animate({
        rotate: '-=45deg'
    });
};
```

In all versions of IE < 9 things go terribly wrong. Rotation animation is crappy, and there is happening something very ugly with alpha transparency of those images, after they have been rotated.

Is it possible to make this work in IE 8 and 7 (and, more or less IE 6?). If not, I will be forced to order it to be done in Flash. But I would like first to try to do it using just css and javascript (svg?). Do you have any tips, for using different technology, or js library?

Thank you in advance for any answers.

EDIT: I actually didn't find solution for rotating png images in IE using CSS and JS. That said, everything was redone using Raphaël, which works very nice even in IE 6.

EDIT2: End result done with Raphael: http://ipm-profil.de/diversity/
I used GIF images, and masked "rough edges" of those circles with SVG (Raphael code).

Comment: I tested the site on IE8 and everything looks fine with the opacity...

Comment: @Cybernate: very strange, I tested it on few computers. I updated question with reference image.

Comment: I didn't notice th black borders in IE8 earlier. Yes you are right, IE8 shows those distortions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would highly recommend using the [Raphaël—JavaScript Library](http://raphaeljs.com/) for this.  Raphaël currently supports Firefox 3.0+, Safari 3.0+, Chrome 5.0+, Opera 9.5+ and Internet Explorer 6.0+ and is very easy to use, and works well with JQuery.

Comment: Thanks, I will be checking that out.

Answer (score 2):

IF you don't care if older browsers can view it IE 9 has add the transform property :

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(15deg) /* for Safari/Chrome */
-moz-transform: rotate(15deg)    /* for Firfox */
-ms-transform: rotate(15deg)     /* for hated IE */
transform: rotate(15deg)         /* The way it should be. */
```

And I found a good JS at
http://www.zachstronaut.com/posts/2009/02/17/animate-css-transforms-firefox-webkit.html the JS is at the bottom of the post.

Comment: Actually they required support for IE 6+. And earlier mentioned Raphaël, allowed me to do that. Thanks for the answer though.

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth doing it in SVG. It will work as is in all browsers including IE9. For IE < 9, you can use [SVGWeb](http://code.google.com/p/svgweb/). Its a Flash shim to make SVG work in browsers that do not support it.